# What does `@Stable` annotation in Jetpack Compose do when applied on function/method?

Tags: performance, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I saw it used on all `Density` methods, and it got me curious.

The annotation docs state that `When applied to a function or a property, the Stable annotation indicates that the function will return the same result if the same parameters are passed in.`, but does this actually affect performance?

I tried testing it (thinking it will skip/cache the result of a function, like if it was called inside `remember`) with the below snippet

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            var counter by remember {
                mutableStateOf(0)
            }
            val key = foo(counter > 0)
            LaunchedEffect(key){
                while (isActive){
                    delay(1000)
                    counter++
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Stable
fun foo(toReturn: Boolean): Boolean{
    Log.d("TEST", toReturn.toString())
    return toReturn
}
```

But it's logging every second, so this annotation didn't affect anything?

Answer (score 7):

The `@Stable` annotation on a function implies that it is a pure function and the compiler plugin make assumptions about the result of the function from its parameters.

This is primarily used in the compiler for inferring if a value is static or equal. For example, the `Double.dp` extension function is marked as `@Stable`. This means that the compiler can infer that, since `42` is a literal, its value will never change. Therefore, since `.dp` is stable, it can infer that the expression `42.dp` will also never change.

The compiler will give up on most operator expression as this is only trivially safe for simple expressions.

`@Stable` never implies skipping or memoizing the result of a function as it doesn't modify what the function does, rather, it is a declaration of what the compiler can assume the function already does (an also a promise by the author of the function that it will always be stable). Only `@Composable` implies rewriting the function to introduce skipping.

If you want to avoid calling `foo` (assuming that foo is expensive) you should use `remember` as in `val key = remember(counter > 0) { foo(counter > 0) }` which will use positional memoization to only call `foo` when the value of the expression `counter > 0` changes.